# Why am I getting the wrong result with the Lucas Lehmer Riesel Test?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, algorithms, modular-arithmetic, primality-test

The [Lucas Lehmer Riesel Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Lehmer%E2%80%93Riesel_test) can test if a number of a certain form is prime or composite. Let $N=6143$. I already know this number is prime so the should find $N \vert u_{n-2}$ but the test ends with $u_{n-2}=531$.

$N$ can be written as $k\cdot2^n-1=3 \cdot 2^{11} -1$ so $u_o=5778$ according to the Wikipedia article since $k=3$.

I have written a simple Python program.

```
p=11
k=3
M=(2**11)-1
u=5778
for i in range(p-2):
  u = ((u*u)-2) % M
  print("u_{} = {}".format(i+1, u))
```

The output is

> u_1 = 759
>   u_2 = 872
>   u_3 = 945
>   u_4 = 531
>   u_5 = 1520
>   u_6 = 1382
>   u_7 = 71
>   u_8 = 945

What is going wrong?

> u_9 = 531

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re not actually using $k$ (nor $p$); you wrote `M=(2**11)-1`instead of `M=k*(2**p)-1`.

Comment: $p$ is used in `range(p-2)`.

Comment: @RiccardoAllegrone: True. I meant in the line `M=(2**11)-1`, where `11` should be `p`. Anyway, that's just an aesthetic thing (which is why I put it in parentheses); the actual error is that $k$ is missing.

Answer (score 1):

I have written this simple Magma program:

```
N := 6143;
u := 5778;
for i in [1..9] do
    u := (u*u - 2) mod N;
end for;
u;
```

Output:

> $0$

Comment: The question isn't "How to do it right?" but "What is going wrong?".

Comment: I think it is possible to understand what goes wrong by seeing what goes right ;)

Comment: Hmm – I'm not sure I agree, but out of respect for that philosophical stance (quite fitting for the owl) I've retracted my downvote. :-) (I made a trivial edit to make that possible.)

Comment: Hmm – three comments that start with "Hmm"...

Comment: Does the test still work if the exponent $p$ is even? For example $191=3 \cdot 2^6-1$. I know in the normal version of the Lucas test it doesn't.

Comment: @northerner: As the Wikipedia article that you linked to says, the starting value $u_0=5778$ is only suitable if $k=3$ and $n\equiv0$ or $3\bmod4$, which is not the case for $191$, where $n=6\equiv2\bmod4$.

Comment: @joriki a better example is $3 \cdot 2^{18}-1=786431$. I'm wondering if the test isn't working because $p$ is even.

Comment: @northerner: Why is $n=18$ a better example? It has the same residue $2$ modulo $4$ as $n=6$ did. The Wikipedia article quite unambiguously states that the initial value $u_0=5778$ is suitable for residues $0$ and $3$ modulo $4$, so it works for even values if they're divisible by $4$.

Comment: @joriki I see what you're saying. The article states "If k = 3", which it is in my example, then $u_0=5778$. I'm not clear on how to interpret the ":" in the sentence, for example does it mean "and" or "or"...

Comment: @northerner For $N=191$, you can use, for example, $u_0 = 110 = V_3(P,1)$ with $P=5$.

Comment: @northerner you have to go on reading the article, because there are two nested if's in the case $k=3$. As a side note, $110$ works also for $786431$.

Comment: @RiccardoAllegrone just to confirm, the way the article is written, it means "both conditions must be met"? For example "If k = 3: if n ≡ 0 or 3 (mod 4)," means k=3 AND  n ≡ 0 or 3 (mod 4)?

Comment: Yes, exactly. So you are not in that case with 191.

Comment: @RiccardoAllegrone sorry you lost me: $95=3\cdot 2^5-1$, this gives $k=3, n=5$. Since $5\equiv1 (\mod 4)$ we CAN'T use $u_0=5778$ on 95. Right? Because it had to have residue of $0$ or $3$. $95 \equiv 3 (\mod 4)$ has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Yes you are definitely right.

Comment: @RiccardoAllegrone isn't it a bit strange how the article states $u_0$ can only be set this way `if 3 does not divide N, ...`If 3 divides N then the number is composite and there is no need for this test. Do I understand correctly? Any idea why the article was written this way? Is it just being pedantic? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Lehmer%E2%80%93Riesel_test

Comment: Probably you can set that particular value of $u_0$ only if $3$ does not divide $N$. The test is needed also if $3 \mid N$, since you don't check for divisibility during the test.

Comment: @RiccardoAllegrone thanks for your help, I am enjoying this discussion but feel free to not reply. It's not actually stated in the article but I think the test only works if $k$ is odd. For example the test doesn't work on $191=6\cdot2^5-1$ because $6$ is even.

Comment: Why? As I said before, for $191$ you can use $u_0 = 110.$

Comment: @RiccardoAllegrone ok, so you used the Lucas sequence $V_3$ to get $u_o$=110? I got confused and thought you had to use $u_0=5778$ if $k=3$ but if $n \not\equiv 0, 3 (\mod{4})$ the test can't be used.

Comment: Yes, you have to do some calculations to get $110$.